# Unable to start mesos-slave after adding containerizer setting on slave

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I want to run docker container through marathon on mesos cluster so I added docker in mesos-slave containerizers configuration with below command.

```
echo 'docker,mesos' > /etc/mesos-slave/containerizers
```

After change mesos-slave its not starting. I am getting error

> Insufficient version of Docker! Please upgrade to >= 1.0.0' in slave logs while restarting: Here below is complete log

```
May 19 15:24:09 flo-doc-nfr-b2b-27 mesos-slave[18055]: W0519 15:24:04.174897 18055 logging.cpp:81] RAW: Received signal SIGTERM from process 19232 of user 0; exiting
May 19 15:24:10 flo-doc-nfr-b2b-27 mesos-slave[19275]: I0519 15:24:10.360828 19275 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
May 19 15:24:10 flo-doc-nfr-b2b-27 mesos-slave[19275]: I0519 15:24:10.361471 19275 main.cpp:156] Build: 2015-05-05 06:16:58 by root
May 19 15:24:10 flo-doc-nfr-b2b-27 mesos-slave[19275]: I0519 15:24:10.361518 19275 main.cpp:158] Version: 0.22.1
May 19 15:24:10 flo-doc-nfr-b2b-27 mesos-slave[19275]: I0519 15:24:10.361543 19275 main.cpp:161] Git tag: 0.22.1
May 19 15:24:10 flo-doc-nfr-b2b-27 mesos-slave[19275]: I0519 15:24:10.361565 19275 main.cpp:165] Git SHA: d6309f92a7f9af3ab61a878403e3d9c284ea87e0
May 19 15:24:10 flo-doc-nfr-b2b-27 mesos-slave[19275]: Failed to create a containerizer: Could not create DockerContainerizer: Insufficient version of Docker! Please upgrade to >= 1.0.0
```

Below is docker version details on mesos-slave:

Client:

- Version:      1.11.1
- API version:  1.23
- Go version:   go1.5.4
- Git commit:   5604cbe
- Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:20:46 2016
- OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:

- Version:      1.11.1
- API version:  1.23
- Go version:   go1.5.4
- Git commit:   5604cbe
- Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:20:46 2016
- OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Mesos version on slave:
0.22.1

If I remove containerizers configuration from slave then its working fine. Mesos, Marathon, Docker are running as service on nodes.

I even tried downgrading mesos to 0.21.1 & docker to 1.9.0 but getting same error.

Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks!!
Sumit

Comment: Why doN#t you use the current Mesos version 0.28.1, but 0.22.1 instead?

Comment: Latest package available on mesosphere apt repo is 0.22.1that's why I used it. For 0.28.1 I have build it manually.

Comment: That's not correct, the version 0.28.1 is available. You have to add the Mesosphere repository. See http://open.mesosphere.com/downloads/mesos/ and https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/

Comment: Yes I agree that 0.28.1 is available but only for debian 8. I have debian 7 machine and last mesos version which is available for debian 7 is  0.22.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use one of 0.24.1, 0.23.1, 0.22.2 or 0.21.2 due to [MESOS-2986](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-2986).

Try to build mesos from source rather than using debs. [Here](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/) is pretty straightforward tutorial how to do it.

```
# Install the packages.
sudo apt-get install -qq tar wget openjdk-7-jdk build-essential python-dev libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules maven libapr1-dev libsvn-dev
# Download the source
wget http://www.apache.org/dist/mesos/0.28.1/mesos-0.28.1.tar.gz
tar -zxf mesos-0.28.1.tar.gz
# Build Mesos
cd mesos-0.28.1
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make -j 8
```

---

**EDIT:**

Marathon require `libmesos` to be placed in the system so after building Mesos from source ensure proper lib will be used. Below extract from [documentation](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/)

> `MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY: bin/start` searches the common
>   installation paths, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`, for the Mesos native
>   library. If the library lives elsewhere in your configuration, set the
>   environment variable `MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY` to its full path.
>
> For example:
>
> `$ MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/Users/bob/libmesos.dylib ./bin/start --master local --zk zk://localhost:2181/marathon`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I tried 0.28.1 by building from source, but somehow slave is shutting down automatically after running for 1-2 minutes.  Getting **Slave asked to shut down by master@10.84.190.67:5050 because 'health check timed out** in slave logs.

Comment: Also my slave and master are running on same host so it could not be possible due to network glitches. Don't know why health check is failing. Any idea?

Comment: Hey Janisz, I rebuild mesos, now mesos master & slave are working fine. But somehow my marathon is not able to detect mesos master. I am getting error **Trying to get '/mesos/json.info_0000000008' in ZooKeeper, Failed to detect a master: Failed to parse data of unknown label 'json.info'**. 

Mesos version is 0.28.0 and Marathon version is 1.1.1.

Comment: Here are command which I am using to start them:

Mesos-master: `./mesos-0.28.1/build/bin/mesos-master.sh --zk=zk://localhost:2181/mesos --quorum=1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos`

Mesos-slave:  `./mesos-0.28.1/build/bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=zk://localhost:2181/mesos --containerizers=docker,mesos`

Marathon:     `./bin/start --master zk://localhost:2181/mesos  --zk zk://localhost:2181/marathon`

Comment: How do you run marathon? I think  the problem is related to `libmesos.so`. Set `MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY` with full path to new `libmesos.so`. More in [docs](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/)

Comment: Tried with MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY still same error. Here is how I am running marathon:

`MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so ./marathon-1.1.1/bin/start --master 10.84.190.67:5050 --disable_revive_offers_for_new_apps`

If I run mesos & marathon without zookeeper then its able to detect master, but not able to run any task on connected salve.

Comment: does `/usr/lib/libmesos.so` goes from your build or from deb package you have installed?

Comment: It comes from build as I have build after purging mesos deb package.

Comment: Hey Janisz, finally I am able to resolve issue. It was because of Java. `Marathon 1.1.1` requires `JDK 8` . I install `JDK8` while building marathon from source but when I installed `zookeeper 3.4.5` it automatically downgraded my java to `JDK7`. Now I am running zookeeper on different node and mesos, marathon on different nodes. Thanks a lot for your help!!